# InputGetKeyDown in OnTriggerStay is called multiple times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game where if an invisible box is touching an object and press "e", text will display depending on what object is touched.  The problem is somethimes (it's kinda random) it will run the text three times.  I've tried putting the inputkey in update, I've tried some Booleans to test if it's been run more than once, I've checked if there's more than one script doing this, but nothing works.

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(name: "e") && other.tag == "Mar Room")
    {
        switch (other.gameObject.name)
        {
            case "Cushion1":

                other.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0);
                other.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-206.849f, 108.2456f, -48.99983f);
                runSentence("CouchText");
                Debug.Log("I have been called cush");
                items += 1;
                break;
            case "Chair":
                other.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 90);
                other.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-182.399f, 108.6756f, -16.16f);
                runSentence("ChairText");
                Debug.Log("I have been called chair");
                items += 1;
                break;
            case "Lamp":
                other.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0);
                other.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-180.779f, 111.3156f, -47.82983f);
                runSentence("LampText");
                items += 1;
                Debug.Log("I have been called lamp");
                break;
            case "Time":
                other.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
                other.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-178.499f, 110.5756f, -37.59983f);
                runSentence("HourglassText");
                items += 1;
                Debug.Log("I have been called time");
                break;
            case "Art":
                other.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
                other.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-190.499f, 113.3056f, -51.31983f);
                runSentence("PictureText");
                items += 1;
                Debug.Log("I have been called art");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Never do input processing in a Physics function

Physics functions run at set intervals while keyboard input runs on renderframe intervals (which are irregular and may be either longer or shorter than Physics steps, causing duplicated or dropped inputs).

You need to instead hold a reference from the physics operation over into the standard `Update()` loop where you check for keypresses and do your actions there:

```
private GameObject nearTo = null

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) {
    if (other.tag == "Mar Room") {
        nearTo = other.gameObject;
    }
}

private void Update() {
    if(nearTo != null && Input.GetKeyDown(name: "e")) {
        //do stuff
        nearTo = null; //set to null when we're done
    }
}
```

Also, I don't think `Input.GetKeyDown(name: "e")` is valid code, but that might have been edited for our convenience rather than actual implementation.

Comment: It's weird to see this kind of code where input is processed in a physics callback function but the reason is because people put it as answer and it actually gets upvoted a lot. Other new users see it and and go with it.

Comment: @Programmer Yeah, I have to fight with a dozen different cargo cult practices on the Minecraft Forge forums on a daily basis. The one that annoys me the most is this concept of `IHasModel` which one semi-new programmer made a tutorial using (in order to cast items/blocks to it in order to call `registerModel()` which just passes **public** information to an external method...)

Answer (score 1):

You might be having an issue where on trigger stay can be called multiple times if you are maybe interacting with multiple triggers. 
GetKeyDown remains true for the entire frame that it is being looked at, so if you have set your physics tick to be at a higher rate than the frame rate you will also be getting multiple calls.

Comment: That's the most understandable solution yet.  I'm new to Unity though, could you clarify or expand on how I would change the frame rate?  I'm assuming it's the Fixed Timestep option in Time Manager, but I'm not sure in what way I would adjust it.

Comment: the other answer is the correct way to avoid having to change your timescale, which is useful if you want to do things like slow mo etc. But yes, fixed timestep is the physics tick rate, you will rarely want to change it, but smaller and everything will move faster, larger and things move slower. as for frame rate, you don't control that other than setting the max speed of it, which is usually set to 60fps